# How to find complexity of this sorting algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Usually it's easy to find complexity: just look at loops (O(n)) and other operations (O(1)) and multiply them if they are nested. But in my code I have no idea what its complexity is, because it's recursive and depth of recursion depends on gaps between values in array.

Here's my code:

```py
def sort(a):
    if len(a) < 2:
        return a
    d = [[] for i in range(len(a))]
    mn = min(a)
    mx = max(a)
    if mn == mx:
        return a
    k = (len(a) - 1) / (mx - mn)
    for i in a:
        d[round((i - mn) * k)].append(i)
    for j, i in enumerate(d):
        if len(set(i)) > 1:
            d[j] = sort(i)
    return [j for i in d for j in i]
```

I tried to test it's efficiency. Here's code I tested my sort with:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import time
    import random

    def timeit(func, loop=1):
        t = time.time()
        for i in range(loop):
            func()
        return time.time() - t

    mine_sort = []
    standard_sort = []
    size = 2
    while size < 1000000:
        arr = [random.randint(1, size) for i in range(size)]
        mine_sort.append(timeit(lambda: sort(arr)))
        standard_sort.append(timeit(lambda: sorted(arr)))
        size *= 2
    print(mine_sort)
    print(standard_sort)
```

What do you think about its time complexity?

Comment: That function is implemented far too poorly and inefficiently for its asymptotic performance to be important. It also isn’t a sort function, so there’s that.

Comment: @Sneftel, why do you say it is not a sort function? Do you have an input example for which the returned list is not sorted?

Comment: @trincot no, I’d misread the source. But it *is* horribly inefficient in constant factors.

Comment: So? The asker is not claiming it is efficient, but is asking about the time complexity.

Comment: @Sneftel It sorts `[random.random() for _ in range(10**6)]` more than twice as fast as [this merge sort](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/154136/219610). So it doesn't seem "horribly inefficient". Please show your much faster one.

Comment: @KellyBundy it’s a bucket sort, not a comparison sort; timing it against a merge sort (particularly that one, which is not a great implementation either) doesn’t demonstrate much. Try sorting `exp(random())` instead and see what happens. But my point was not that it’s less efficient than other sorting algorithms, but that it’s inefficient for *that* algorithm.

Comment: @Sneftel Ok I tried `[exp(random()) for _ in range(10**6)]` and what happened was that it was about three times faster than that other sorter. What did you expect? And ok, let's see your much faster *bucket sort* then.

Comment: @KellyBundy That’s surprising, and I’d have to dig into it to see why you’re getting those results. But in any case, the basic problem here is overallocation and manual concatenation. Bucket sort is ideally implemented using only two arrays (source and destination), with a pre-scan to allocate indices in the destination for each bucket; this variant is known as “histogram sort” (though it’s basically the same algorithm).

Comment: @Sneftel Still waiting to see the code.

Comment: @KellyBundy weird, why did you not just Google “histogram sort”? I’m not going to code one up for you. I’m on a cellphone here. (And not interested in a pissing contest.)

Comment: @Sneftel I did google it, didn't find one. Plus if it turns out similarly fast, you might just claim that it's bad, too. And I'm not the one who badmouthed this solution, claiming it's horribly inefficient. If you do that, I do expect you to back that claim up. And I'm on a phone, too.

Comment: Dude, I’m telling you what the relative state of the art in bucket sorts is. If you don’t want to believe some random internet person, I’m sure TAOCP and *Introduction to Algorithms* say the same thing. It’s not a new, or exotic, algorithm.

Comment: @Sneftel I doubt those talk about Python at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a variant of [bucket sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort).

In this variant, the number of buckets is set to be the same as the number of elements in the list. Each bucket represents a range of equal size. The values are then distributed over the buckets determined by the range they belong to. Then each bucket that then still has more than one element, is sorted recursively. Finally the sorted buckets are concatenated into a list that is guaranteed to be sorted.

If the input values have a homogeneous distribution, each bucket could end up with one value, and then no recursive calls are made. This represents a best case with a time complexity of O(). Also less homogeneous distributions will lead to buckets that have only a few values, and some empty buckets, still giving a O() time complexity.

If the input values are really badly distributed, it could happen in the worst case that one value ends up in one bucket, and all the others in one other bucket. Then the recursive call on the latter bucket could have the same happening again...etc. This could be the case if the input values are taken from an exponential sequence, where the base of the exponentiation is greater than the number of values in the list. For example [1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, ..., 10<sup>9</sup>]. This leads to O() recursive calls, where the total complexity is O(1 + 2 + 3 + ... + ), which is O(²).

So:

- Best and average case: O()
- Worst case: O(²)